# Array size is always ten

Tags: java

I have recently started having a problem where any array I create regardless of the size I intend will be size ten. Is this a common problem? Should I simply re install Jgrasp? if this isn't clear here is some code:

```
int [] array = new int[34];
```

Will create an array of length ten, while still saying it is length 34. I can tell this from using the debugger. Any help is appreciated

Comment: we need more relevant code

Comment: Justify your statement

Comment: @Cameron Massey what does this return ` public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[34];
        System.out.println(array.length);
    }`

Comment: It printed out the correct length. It all makes sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your debugger is probably only showing you the first 10 items in the array. This is a common feature in debugging tools.

Answer (score 0):

You could fill all 34 places and if there is an "ArrayOutOfBounds" exception you will see it doesn't work..

and why are you using array if you could use a List or a Vector?

```
Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<>(); //create new Vector
vector.add(5); // add value in vector
```

would be much easier to handle and manage